# Laracsv UTF-8 encoding

Tags: laravel, csv, encoding, utf-8

looking for solution how to export data from database to CSV with UTF-8 encoding. Laravel framework. Using Laracsv plugin. But getting data with broken symbols (image below), and function which using to get a list:

[image]

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $list_id = new Event;
        $list_id = $request->input('event_id');
        $users = Player::where('event_id',$list_id)->get(); // All users
        $csvExporter = new \Laracsv\Export();
        $csvExporter->build($users, ['name', 'surname', 'birtday', 'city', 'country', 'rating', 'tel', 'email', 'group'])->download();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

As per package's documentation , It doesn't allow to pass `headers` in download. A simple workaround could be

1. Get `writer` object which the package is using `League/CSV`

   ```
   $writer = $csvExporter->build($user, ['name', 'surname', 'birtday', 'city', 'country', 'rating', 'tel', 'email', 'group'])->getCSV();
   ```

[Reference ^](https://github.com/usmanhalalit/laracsv/blob/4e3379463d63c84d89f832ec683d80b874290f9e/src/Laracsv/Export.php#L96)

2. Now save this file

   ```
   Storage::disk('local')->put('download.csv', $writer->getContent());
   ```

[Refernce ^](https://csv.thephpleague.com/9.0/writer/).

3.Download this via `response` object

```
return response()->download('patht-to-file', 'download.csv', ['Content-Type' => 'text/csv; charset=utf-8'])
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for your answer, but with your example I'm getting ErrorException Undefined variable: writer

Comment: I fixed a variable name typo in my code above. Check if that was the reason. Else please mention which line is causing error.

Comment: Hi now code is working, but I still getting a list without  UTF-8 coding

Comment: Did you check request log of your download request if the response header has `charset` mentioned?

Answer (score 0):

You can actually add headers to your download but you need to fall back to the underlying League CSV library.

First you need to get the underlying League CSV instance by calling:

```
$csv = $csvExporter->getCsv();
```

Then in order for Microsoft Excel to properly recognize the file as a UTF8 CSV you also need to add a BOM (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark). To do that you can once again use League CSV's features:

```
$csv->setOutputBOM(\League\Csv\Reader::BOM_UTF8);
```

Then return the csv string as a Laravel response object with headers like this:

```
return response((string) $csv)
        ->header('Content-Type', 'text/csv; charset=UTF-8')
        ->header('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename="whatever.csv");
```